# HTML comments PHP out, but why?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm trying to fill an select input with data from database. the php code itself works, but when i try to build a html form it wrecks up.

Heres my code (start.html):

```
[...]
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>Schueler:</p>
 <select name="schueler">
 <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "test", "test01", "Noten");
    $query = "SELECT id, vorname, nachname FROM schueler";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo '<option value="' .htmlspecialchars($row['id']).'">' 
            .htmlspecialchars($row['vorname'])
            .' '.
            htmlspecialchars($row['nachname']).'</option>';
        }
 ?>
 </select>
[...]
```

But what I get on loading the page is this:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>Schueler:</p>
 <select name="schueler">
 <!--?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "test", "test01", "Noten");
    $query = "SELECT id, vorname, nachname FROM schueler";
    $result = $mysqli--->query($query);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo '<option value="' .htmlspecialchars($row['id']).'">' 
            .htmlspecialchars($row['vorname'])
            .' '.
            htmlspecialchars($row['nachname']).'</option>';
        }
?>"
 </select>
[...]
```

As you can see, the problem is most likely, that the php command is commented when running the page. Can you help or provide some ideas?

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure your server is running php, and are you sure your file has a .php file extension? Actually I'd bet you're not using the .php file extension.

Comment: *But what I get on loading the page is this:* Please explain. Where do you see this exactly? Is the `while` loaded as well?

Comment: It isn't normal behavior than `<?` is changed to HTML comment `<!--?`. Do you use any framework, st. other than 'pure' PHP?

Comment: @treegarden: yes the Server is running php. as the code inside php tag can run itself. then, you're right that i'm not using .php file extension, but neither this or .html works.

Comment: @Loko: I can see this if i check elements on the webpage in chrome (using Ctrl+Shift+i). what do you mean by `while` loaded as well?

Comment: @panther: i'm running the webserver on a Synology DS215j, as far as I know it has complete php support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Heres my code (*start.html*):

Rename the file to `start.php` in order to let the server know it needs to be parsed by the `PHP` interpreter.

#### Update (following up your comment about an empty `<SELECT>` element):

An empty `<SELECT>` element means the `while()` loop does not execute.

Take a look at the generated source code (command `View source` in your browser) and look for possible error or warning messages where you expect something else (inside the `<SELECT>` element).

If there is nothing there then enable the reporting and displaying of errors; put [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [`ini_set('display_errors', '1');`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) on top of the script.

Add code to check the query result (`if ($result != FALSE)`) before trying to fetch rows from it.

It's also possible that the connection fails. Check the value of [`$mysqli->connect_errno`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php) right after you create `$mysqli`. If it is not `0` then the connection failed. You can find the reason in [`$mysqli->connect_error`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php).

Also make sure the table `schueler` contains some data to be returned by the query.

Comment: thank you, that took me one step further. Now I'm only getting an empty combobox.

Comment: I updated the response with basic directions for finding the error.

Comment: That solved the problem. I added a typo in my code after asking this question. Now it works like a charm. Thank you.